How can I close a "dummy" progress bar on 100% in Winforms?
I'm writing a small Winforms project that runs a certain task which completes almost instantaneously. So I want to add a "dummy" progress bar in a popup dialog to enhance the user experience.
The bar doesn't measure anything, it just iterates a value from 0 to a given maximum. When the progress bar reaches its Maximum value, the dialog should close automatically. The problem I'm having is that the dialog always closes when the bar is only at about 90 percent.
Following an answer from user "Moon soon" in this SO post, I coded my progress bar dialog this way:
public partial class ProgressBar : Form
{
    public System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar Progressbar { get { return this.progressBar1; } }

    public ProgressBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void RunAsync(Action action)
    {
        Task.Run(action);
    }
}

Then in my main form, I show the progress bar dialog using method showProgressBar:
private void showProgressBar()
{
    ProgressBar prog = new ProgressBar();

    prog.Progressbar.Value = 0;
    prog.Progressbar.Maximum = 200;

    prog.RunAsync(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < prog.Progressbar.Maximum; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            prog.Progressbar.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
            {
                prog.Progressbar.Value += 1;

                //close the dialog when value equals maximum
                if (prog.Progressbar.Value == prog.Progressbar.Maximum)
                {
                    prog.Close();
                    prog.Dispose();
                }
            }));
        }
    });

    prog.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    prog.ShowDialog();
}

This works -- the dialog closes when the loop completes -- but the dialog closes before the progress bar hits 100% visually.
What am I doing wrong?

It's not your error. This is how animation works in the ProgressBar. The only point: You destroy the ProgressBar as soon as it reaches the maximum.

Following the comment above: you can add a small async delay when the progress-bar reaches the maximum, and only then destroy it.

I usually use ProgressBarStyle.Marquee in such fast processes.

The visual feedback on a ProgressBar trails in time to the .Value set. So adding about 1 second of delay before closing should fix this issue. You can create your own progress bar by resizing the width of a label with some background color specified.

Fire-and-forget for tasks is bad practice (Task.Run(action)). You should await the result of Task.Run() to unwrap any exceptions. Strange things can happen when you don't await the Task returned by Task.Run(). See this article written by Steven Cleary: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming

The problem is that once the progress-bar reaches its Maximum, you immediatly close and dispose it (before allowing it to render the final animation for being at 100%).
You can solve it by adding a small async delay (1 second did the trick in my test, you can change it according to your preference) before closing and disposing the progress-bar:
private void showProgressBar()
{
    ProgressBar prog = new ProgressBar();

    prog.Progressbar.Value = 0;
    prog.Progressbar.Maximum = 200;

    prog.RunAsync(() => 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < prog.Progressbar.Maximum; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            //-------------------------------------------vvvvv------
            prog.Progressbar.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(async () =>
            {
                prog.Progressbar.Value += 1;

                if (prog.Progressbar.Value == prog.Progressbar.Maximum)
                {
                    // Async delay of 1 second,
                    //  before closing and disposing the progress bar:
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    prog.Close();
                    prog.Dispose();
                }
            }));
        }
    });

    prog.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    prog.ShowDialog();
}

Note:
The lambda that updates the progress bar is marked async, so that it will be able to await an aync delay. Performing the delay synchronously (using e.g. Thread.Sleep) will not let you achieve what you want because in that case the UI thread will not be free to render the final state animation.
